# How to create an add to queue option in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django. I have a set of videos with URL. I want to have an option of add to queue, where when i click on the video link and add the URL to queue it displays all the videos(the ones added to queue) in the queue in a template. Please let me know how should I approach this.

Comment: Do you want the queue server-side (stored in database) or client-side?

Comment: I want both, adding to queue option on the UI(client side) and then to be stored in a database(server side)

Comment: It is more like creating a playlist for every user where they can add video links(like a youtube add to Favs or Youtube "like" list). This playlist will then be displayed in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have a `Playlist` Model. Something like this

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='playlists')
    entries = models.ManyToManyField(Video)
```

Then you can perform queries like so

```
new_playlist = Playlist(owner=user_instance)
new_playlist.save()
new_playlist.entries.add(video_instance)

all_of_users_playlist = user_instance.playlists.all()

playlist_videoes = playlist_instance.entries.all()
```

Comment: As per you suggestions I have come up with the below model. 
I need to have two such playlists- one for TV-shows and other for the TV episodes. So when the user adds TV shows to the playlist it will show up in his Favorites and similar for Episodes.       
Also, I already have User, Shows, Episode classes which I want to include in the playlist
So my model is:
'Class PlaylistShows(models.Model)
title= models.CharField(Max_length=200)
user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
shows_link=models.ManyToMany(Shows)'

simlar class for PlayListEpisodes.
Please let me know if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

As per you suggestions I have come up with the below model. 
I need to have two such playlists- one for TV-shows and other for the TV episodes. So when the user adds TV shows to the playlist it will show up in his Favorites and similar for Episodes.
Also, I already have User, Shows, Episode classes which I want to include in the playlist
So my model is:

```
Class PlaylistShows(models.Model)
title= models.CharField(Max_length=200)
user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
shows_link=models.ManyToMany(Shows)
```

simlar class for PlayListEpisodes.
Please let me know if this is a good approach.